# Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognised. Unable to parse query in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hi i am trying to create a report in SSRS , and i am using below query for taking date difference and comparison.

```
IIF ((CAST(issues.created_at as smalldatetime)) = (CAST(sprints.created_at as smalldatetime)) OR (DATEDIFF(Minute,CAST(sprints.created_at as smalldatetime), CAST(issues.created_at as smalldatetime)) < 2),1,0) as new_task
```

but i am getting error "Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognised. Unable to parse query"

is there anything i need to change in the code.

Comment: Are you using that derived field in a SELECT statement? Do you get the error if you add SELECT before the IIF?

Comment: I am using select statement before this statement and this is only one selection of fields. i am having  other field selection statements.

Comment: That part of your query is valid. Can you post the complete query.

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server are you using? -> SELECT @@VERSION.

Comment: Iif maybe not valid for your sql server version. Prefer case statements which are sql standard and backward compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your version of SQL Server does not support the IIF (added in 2012).

Change it to a CASE statement which has the same functionality.

```
SELECT...,
CASE WHEN CAST(issues.created_at AS SMALLDATETIME) = CAST(sprints.created_at AS SMALLDATETIME) 
                OR DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(sprints.created_at AS SMALLDATETIME), CAST(issues.created_at AS SMALLDATETIME)) < 2
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_task
```

Comment: Accepting this answer , this fix the issue. The issue was with the SQL server version only, Thank you